# HTTP get request with Axios gets sent with the local host IP at the beginning of the URL

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I am trying to sent an HTTP request with Axios, but I get a 404 error. The reason is that the request gets sent with the local host IP at the beginning of the URL, why is this happening?

JS:

```
function getWeather() {

  axios.get('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', {
    params: {
      lat: 30.18,
      lon: 30.87,
      appid: '57d9478bc08bc211f405f45b93b79272'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })

  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
};
getWeather();
```

ERROR:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=30.18&lon=30.87&appid=57d9478b#####################3b79272 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the URL argument for Axios, you are not specifying the protocol to use for your API request (probably HTTP). Because of that, Axios interprets it as a relative URL path and adds the path of your local server, because it needs a full URL to make the request.

You can easily fix it by adding the http:// prefix:

```
axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', {
```

Comment: I have observed this but I was wondering if this behavior is documented anywhere.. Please help with a ref.

Answer (score 3):

you can config the axios base url before your request

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org';
axios.get('/data/2.5/weather')
```

Comment: axios.defaults.baseURL is the correct way to declare your base url if you are going to export axios as axios.create.....

Answer (score 1):

To have full control over axios' base URL, you can specify `baseURL` at `AxiosInstance` creation:

```
    var getBaseUrl = () => {
        // custom base URL logic examples:
        // - to request a current URL without the search parameters part:
        let baseUrl = window.location.href.slice(0, -window.location.search.length);

        //// or to insert '/api' after the host part
        //let baseUrl = window.location.host + '/api' + window.location.pathname;

        // ensure slash at the end
        if (baseUrl[baseUrl.length - 1] != '/') baseUrl = baseUrl + '/';

        return baseUrl;
    };

    var axiosConfig = {
        baseURL: this.getBaseUrl(),
    };
    var axiosInstance = axios.create(axiosConfig);

    axiosInstance.get('/your-path')
       .then(res => {
           // ...
       });
       // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same issue , my ".env" file was like
`API_URL = 'https://--My-API_URL--'`
Here i faced the same issue , after that replaced the env link by double-quotation that i s changed to this
`API_URL = "https://--My-API_URL--"` and the issue is solved
Reason: axios could not understand the http or https protocol in the env-url , so the base-url is concatinated .

Answer (score 0):

My ".env" file experienced the same issue. Using ''replace “” is a good idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).