# I am having problem using http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http-proxy-middleware

I have two servers running in my backend, because of that I have to use the [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware#shorthand) package but I am encountering some problems.

This is my code in the frontend which is running on localhost:3000

```
axios("/api2/login",data)
    .then((res) => {
});
```

This is my code in the backend which is running on localhost:5001

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api2', {target: 'http://localhost:5001', changeOrigin: true}))

app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Logged In");
});
```

This code is no working showing this error in the browser's console

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api2/login 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you share the code of your other server port 3000?

Comment: Do you mean the code of my another server running on port 5000?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's hitting `localhost:3000` instead of `localhost:5001` which is where your server is running from.

```
axios("http://localhost:5001/api2/login",data)
    .then((res) => {
});
```

You can also set the baseURL in axios. [HTTP get request with Axios gets sent with the local host IP at the beginning of the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960497/http-get-request-with-axios-gets-sent-with-the-local-host-ip-at-the-beginning-of)

Comment: That's what I was doing before using this package, but I want to deploy this project that is why I want to use a proxy otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your server is listening on port 5001. So, you need to proxy your requests from 3000 to 5001. You can do that in the react application by setting the proxy value in package.json:

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:5001",
```

For more information about this subject, check [the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).

#### Edit for the configuration explained in the comment section

First in package.json:

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:5002",
```

Create a new server (**proxyserver**)  which will be listening in port 5002:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware'); 
const app = express(); 

// redirection for first server 5000
app.use('/api1', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:5000', changeOrigin: true })); 

// redirection for second server 5001
app.use('/api2', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:5001', changeOrigin: true })); 

app.listen(5002);
```

For the other servers (5000 and 5001) you don't need to redirect the requests. Just make sure they're listening on the right ports (5000 and 5001), for example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 

app.post("/api2/login", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Logged In");
});

app.listen(5001);
```

Comment: But I have two servers running one on 5000 and the other on 5001, that's why I am using this package.

Comment: Well, you need to choose at least one server, then proxy again the requests to the other server. Or another elegant solution you create another server which only proxy requests ( for example in port 5002) then this server will proxy the requests to the other two 5000 and 5001.

Comment: The issue you're having above is not caused by your backend configuration but because of your front requests not even reaching one server!

Comment: If possible, can you please provide an example link for the same

Comment: I'll edit the answer, for a minimal solution

Comment: Made the above changes, still getting the same error :-(

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65681070/14886545) along with some changes,

I changed my Axios request code to:

```
axios({
    method: "POST",
    data: user,
    withCredentials: true,
    url: "/api2/login",
}).then((res) => {})
```

**Otherwise, the proxy server was treating it as a GET request.**

Secondly, I changed the proxy endpoint code int the proxy server as:

```
app.use('/api2', createProxyMiddleware({ 
    target: 'http://localhost:5001', 
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        [`^/api2`]: '',
    },
}));
```

**Further information about the proxy endpoint change can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/node-js-proxy-server).**